# Renaming directory on remote server with Fabric

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I've the following problem with renamig directories, using:

```
$> mv /homex/p4blo/testWebDir/app1 /homex/p4blo/testWebDir/app1_backup
```

I'd like to rename app1 directory to app1_backup in the same path (simply rename only). If there is no app1_backup folder it's okay, but if there is, app1 lands in app1_backup/app1.

How should I proceed with this. In case, there IS app1_backup directory at the beginning, it should be dropped and replaced by new app1_backup folder (the one renamed from app1).

Answer (score 0):

The command you pass to `fabric.run` is executed through a shell process (eg. `/bin/bash -l -c "<command>"`) by default. Feel free to use any kind of shell script in there:

```
run(''' srcdir=/homex/p4blo/testWebDir/app1
        [[ -e ${srcdir}_backup ]] && rm -rfv ${srcdir}_backup 
        [[ -e ${srcdir} ]] && mv -v ${srcdir} ${srcdir}_backup ''')
```